# При заголовке появляется разрыв между шапкой и контентом

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<setction id="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>dobro</h1>
    </div>
</setction>
```

Но если я не буду ставить заголовок или параграф, то всё будет выглядеть так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<setction id="content">
    <div class="main">
        Просто слова без заголовка
    </div>
</setction>


.main{
width:100%;     
height: 1000px;
padding:0;
font-size:0.875em;
color: black;
background: #2f2e2e;}
```

Код страницы контента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
padding-top: 1px;
```

Решение на данный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить margin 0

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: black;
  background: #2f2e2e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\test\style\main.css">
  <script src="D:\test\js\adaptiveMenu.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testwrap">
    <div id="test">
      <setction id="content">
        <div class="main">
          <h1>dobro</h1>
        </div>
      </setction>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```